# What are the options of PCIe dev boards these days?

Tags: pcie

do you know if there is any fpga PCIe dev board that would support adding/removing pcie capabilities and examining tlps?

Comment: See [what not to ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Well excuuuse me

Comment: This can still be generically answered tho. Yes there are dev boards that have what you say find it on your own. Or no this is all made up there is no such dev board

Comment: I think @Transistor was getting at was this question is rather vague. It's like asking, "What car do you think I should get?" without listing what type car you need to get. I think to improve this question to be more compatible with this website is to ask us what type of solution you're looking for. Perhaps consulting a vendor would be a really very helpful source to answer your questions :)

Comment: But that is not the question! The question is there such car at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a feature of the dev board so much as a feature of the PCIe hardware on the FPGA. At any rate, the PCIe hard cores on Xilinx Ultrascale parts will allow you to add capabilities, and the interface to the core is at the transaction layer. You can't look at TLPs used within the core (configuration TLPs), though.

Comment: Isn't it also a feature of the dev board having suitably routed differential pairs and connectors?

Comment: Well yeah, but OP is asking about some very specific capabilities, such as messing with the configuration space. So first you need an FPGA that provides these capabilities, then you find/make a board with that FPGA that has the right connectors. My point is that OP may need a very specific FPGA, or might need to use a soft PCIe IP core instead of the integrated hard IP.